# Jenkins git fetch fails with unknown option --progress

Tags: git, jenkins

We have been using jenkins to build a project for over two years. We recently updated the jenkins and plugins (we need the maven-3 features), and now it's unable to do a simple git fetch. Here's the error message:

```
    FATAL: Failed to fetch from https://github.com/powertac/sample-broker.git
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from https://github.com/powertac/sample-broker.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:625)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:847)
    ...
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/powertac/sample-broker.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 129:
stdout: 
stderr: error: unknown option `progress'
usage: git fetch [options] [ ..]
```

As you can see, the command line issued by jenkins contains an unknown option --progress. I have searched through the config files and cannot find where this is coming from. Here are the relevant version numbers:

Jenkins: 1.550
JenkinsGitPlugin: 2.0.1
git: 1.7.0.4
OS: Ubuntu 10.04

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it is hardcoded in [Git Client Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Client+Plugin), which is dependency for [Git Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin).

Git `--progress` option for **fetch** command [become available](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9839018e874d4f15e820e1272f1ac575186c4fdc) in version 1.7.1.

Git Client Plugin [started using](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-client-plugin/commit/a3d3d548842d6a9bafbf9f2eb45729478be7dbbc) `--progress` option for git **fetch** command since version 1.5.0.

Prior to that, in version 1.4.6, Git Client Plugin used git **clone** command instead of **fetch**, and [made a check](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-client-plugin/blob/git-client-1.4.6/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/gitclient/CliGitAPIImpl.java#L283) of installed git version before deciding whether to use `--progress` option (which [become available](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5a518ad4679c91f0d0afd38fcc3cbf04e8699c46) for git **clone** command since git version 1.7.0).

So possible ways to solve your problem, starting with the most straightforward one, are:

- get a newer (1.7.1+) version of git on your system; getting up-to-date versions of software on Ubuntu may become a problem, so you might want to check [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2061057)
- ask Git Client Plugin team to add support for git 1.7.0, wait until they release new version, and then use it
- install older (1.4.6) version of Git Client Plugin; beware that you may also need to downgrade Git Plugin in order to preserve compatibility
- patch Git Client Plugin on your own locally
- ...come up with something even more painful :)

Comment: Thanks for the great detective work. I've fixed this in https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-client-plugin/commit/24903f5ef3d0e1cb659e605196828ce702b10b05